How to calculate number of weeks between two variables in r where years have 52 and 53 weeks according to iso?
Hey I have a dataset which has two variables of dates in the following format: YYWW. For example 0951 is year 2009 and week 51 of that year and so on.
What I want is to create a new variable where it will show the number of weeks in between those dates including the start and end week as well. The problem is also that 2009 and 2015 have 53 weeks but 2010 has only 52 weeks. How to to also take care of that effectively?
df <- data.frame(date_start = c("0951", "0952", "1001", "1551"),
date_end = c("1052", "1003", "1144", "1651"))


library(dplyr)

mutate(df, 
        start=as.Date(paste0(date_start, 1), format="%y%U%u"),
        end=as.Date(paste0(date_end, 1), format="%y%U%u"),
        weeks=difftime(end, start, units="weeks")+1)


  date_start date_end      start        end    weeks
1       0951     1052 2009-12-21 2010-12-27 54 weeks
2       0952     1003 2009-12-28 2010-01-18  4 weeks
3       1001     1144 2010-01-04 2011-10-31 96 weeks
4       1551     1651 2015-12-21 2016-12-19 53 weeks


From ?strptime:

%u Weekday as a decimal number (1–7, Monday is 1).


%U Week of the year as decimal number (00–53) using Sunday as the
first day 1 of the week (and typically with the first Sunday of the
year as day 1 of week 1). The US convention.


for 2009 week 51 starts on the 14 of December and finishes on the 20th of December according to this site: https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2009 . But here the week starts on the 21st of December. Is there something wrong? Thanks for helping out

That website uses Week 01 as the first week while R uses Week 00. In any case, the differences between the two dates should be correct.

You might add that there's also %V—the ISO 8601 convention.

@jay.sf - yes, but according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541993/issue-with-r-ddate-format-y-v it is better to use "%U".

@Edward Yes, that's what I meant, your decision why using "$U".

When dealing with ISO8601 years & weeks, you can use {ISOweek} package to help with parsing.
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(ISOweek)

df <- data.frame(date_start = c("0951", "0952", "1001", "1551"),
                 date_end = c("1052", "1003", "1144", "1651"))

# transform to proper ISO format
# start dates set to Mondays (1st  day of ISO weeks),
# end   dates set to Sundays (last day of ISO weeks);
# parse ISO8601 dates with ISOweek2date, get time difference in weeks, round up
df |> 
  mutate(start_iso = str_replace(date_start, "(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "20\\1-W\\2\\-1"),
         end_iso   = str_replace(date_end,   "(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "20\\1-W\\2\\-7"), 
         across(ends_with("_iso"), ISOweek2date, .names = "{.col}_dt"),
         weeks = difftime(end_iso_dt, start_iso_dt, units = "weeks") |> as.numeric() |> ceiling())

#>   date_start date_end  start_iso    end_iso start_iso_dt end_iso_dt weeks
#> 1       0951     1052 2009-W51-1 2010-W52-7   2009-12-14 2011-01-02    55
#> 2       0952     1003 2009-W52-1 2010-W03-7   2009-12-21 2010-01-24     5
#> 3       1001     1144 2010-W01-1 2011-W44-7   2010-01-04 2011-11-06    96
#> 4       1551     1651 2015-W51-1 2016-W51-7   2015-12-14 2016-12-25    54

Created on 2024-07-04 with reprex v2.1.0
